# WMIC in Linux return [wmi/wmic.c:212:main()] ERROR: Retrieve result data

Tags: wmic

I try to use wmic in java to get device info, and it works success when I use CLI with command wmic -U user%password //192.168.xxx.xx "select name,status from Win32_service" | grep WinRM directly,
I have ask my colleague,and he said the error must be cause by the Cmd String array because String result get a value  [wmi/wmic.c:212:main()] ERROR: Retrieve result data, but I just can't find what's wrong.

Here is my code:

```
String[] Cmd = new String[]{"wmic", "-U", "user%password", "//192.168.xxx.xx", "\"select name,status from Win32_service\" | grep WinRM"};
        try {
            for (String s : Cmd) {
                System.out.println("Cmmand String:" + s);
            }
            Process proc = null;
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(linuxCmd);
            proc.getOutputStream().close();

            InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("x-windows-950")); //Using charset "x-windows-950" For the decode of the Traditional Chinese Windows.!!!                
            LineNumberReader input = new LineNumberReader(ir);
            String line;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
//                System.out.println("Column Name: " + line);
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
//                    logger.debug("Result" + input.getLineNumber() + ":" + line);
                sb.append(line.trim()).append("\n");
            }
            String result = sb.toString().trim();
            System.out.println("Result: " + result);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
```

Comment: How is this Linux if it's querying Windows service?

Comment: I think is OK because the device being monitored work querying Windows service? it work when I use CLI with command wmic -U user%password //192.168.xxx.xx "select name,status from Win32_service" | grep on linux, and I am confused about the meaning of Error Retrieve result data and what cause it.

Comment: I find the error is caused by the format, it works if I change "\"select name,status from Win32_service\" | grep WinRM" to  "select name,status from Win32_service",but I still don’t know how to deal with |grep WinRM should I put it in the same array index with query ?

Answer (score 0):

The ERROR occur because it seem grep as part of wmi query,It works after using where instead of grep.